# Issue with a puzzle solution in C language (CodeChef.com)

Tags: c, puzzle, factorial

i've made my code to solve a puzzle at http://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL

According to what i've tested, the program works right for any string of number. Apparently, the CodeChef website reports a wrong output.

Can anyone correct me on this?

Here's what I coded:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i,iterations,target,victim1,victim2,victim3;

    scanf("%d",&iterations); //take the number of acceptable iterations.

    for(i=0;i<iterations;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &target); //take the number as a target input the user want's to calculate on.
        victim1=target/5;
        victim2=victim1;

        while(victim1>=5)
        {
            victim1=(victim1)/5;
            victim3=victim3+victim1;
        }

        printf("%d\n",victim2+victim3);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First of all, what is the expected output for some specified input, and what is the actual output? Second, this should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: My apologies. I'll keep that in mind. The bold text is the output for each input. The website has a rule that in such puzzles, the output should be one after the other input and not as a accepting all inputs at once and throwing out all output at once. Hence, this:

8
4
**0**
5
**1**
25
**6**
100
**25**
1000
**254**
100000
**25053**
9999999
**2505045**
999999999
**250505035**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`victim3` is never initialized... so it could start at any value.

You should likely initialize `victim3` to be `0`.

Comment: That did the job. I forgot the fact that in C, the default values for variables are initialized to garbage. Thanks!

Comment: More accurately, they are not initialized at all.   Their starting value is whatever happens to be left over in that memory location from whatever was there before.